# Trouble removing a Laravel package

Tags: laravel-4

I have recently cloned my bitbucket repo and I'm in the process of moving it to a new live directory.

Upon deploying my codebase to the new live directory, I got a "Class not found" error related to the thujohn/twitter package. So I attempted to remove the package altogether by using:

```
composer remove thujohn/twitter
```

Unfortunately, I get this error back:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Thujohn\Twitter\TwitterServiceProvider' not found in /home/forge/hbavault.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 158
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/forge/site.com/artisan:0
PHP   2. require_once() /home/forge/site.com/artisan:30
PHP   3. require() /home/forge/site.com/bootstrap/start.php:67
PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load() /home/forge/site.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php:210
PHP   5. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->createProvider() /home/forge/site.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:82
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Thujohn\\Twitter\\TwitterServiceProvider' not found","file":"\/home\/forge\/site.com\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/ProviderRepository.php","line":158}}
```

I've removed reference to the package from my composer.json file and under providers and aliases in the config/app.php file

It is also removed from the two places I was using it in my code.

Any ideas as to what else I need to do to eliminate this error and entirely remove the package?

Comment: Run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @lukasgeiter  I tried that and then composer update, but I get the same 'Class 'Thujohn\Twitter\TwitterServiceProvider' not found' error.

Comment: Did you cache your config? Try running `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I still get the same error.   php artisan config:clear
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Thujohn\Twitter\TwitterServiceProvider' not found in /home/forge/site.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 158

Comment: Do you get the error in response to running `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: yes, that error is in response to the php artisan config:clear

Comment: Okay see if you can find `storage/meta/services.json` and delete that file. (No worries it will be generated again)

Comment: Still didn't work. At this point I think I'll just delete the forge provision and start over.  Thanks for you help though.

Comment: Too bad. Can you somehow do a search over everything for `TwitterServiceProvider`?